# How to change Column Index of IgxGrid dynamically?

Tags: angular, ignite-ui-angular, igx-grid

I need to apply user settings on IgxGrid. What I am trying is that whenever a user reorders columns, I am saving the column indices in my database and next time when the user opens the same grid; I need to show the same settings on grid which he saved previously. But when I try to set the column index it says that there is no setter for index property. How can I achieve the functionality to change column indices dynamically? Here is what i am trying to do,

```
for (var iterator = 0; iterator < gridSettings.ColumnSettings.length; iterator++) {          

      if (this.componentRef.columns != null) {
        for (let colIndex = 0; colIndex < this.componentRef.columns.length; colIndex++) {

          if (this.componentRef.columns[colIndex].field == gridSettings.ColumnSettings[iterator].Key) {    

            this.componentRef.columns[colIndex].width = gridSettings.ColumnSettings[iterator].Width;
            this.componentRef.columns[colIndex].index = gridSettings.ColumnSettings[iterator].Index;

            break;
          }
        }
      }
```

Here is the error which I am encountring,

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property
>   index of [object Object] which has only a getter  TypeError: Cannot
>   set property index of [object Object] which has only a getter

Answer (score 0):

Do you bind your initial rendering of the igx-grid columns to your column settings? If yes, then the `*ngFor` would render the columns with the indices that they hold in the `ColumnSettings` collection.

```
<igx-column *ngFor="let column of gridSettings.ColumnSettings" [width]="column.width">
  ...
</igx-column>
```

Instead of holding the `index` as a property of the objects in the `ColumnSettings` array, reorder the array based on the indices. Then rearrange the `ColumnSettings` array based on the `visibleIndex` property of the `igx-column` component, rather than the `index` property.

The reason to not have an index setter is that when an index of a column changes, the column should either swap with the column at the target index, or the indices of all columns after the target should be incremented up to the source. The behavior of an index setter becomes more complex and opens up for more inconsistencies with pinned columns, as after pinning, the index in the array is no longer reflected by the UI, as a column could be on index 5, but if it's pinned, then it's frozen at the beginning of the grid.

Comment: First of all thank you for your response. I have tried it earlier to save reordered column collection but it did not reorder columns in grid even though collection was saved correctly. 

Here is how I tried to do so,
this.componentRef.columns.splice(0, this.componentRef.columns.length);
this.componentRef.columns.push(...columnComponentsWithNewOrder);

 this.componentRef.reflow();

Comment: If you want to try it at runtime, instead of changing the componentRef columns, do it to your ColumnSettings, which you're bound to, and then call detectChanges() manually on your ChangeDetectorRef.